# show android item on button click

Tags: android, layout

I am an android beginner , I have two buttons in my activity A & B.Help me make button B hidden and show it when button A is clicked !

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: We were all beginners at some point. What have you tried? Have you done any research at least?

Comment: @A--C Yes I googled it , no results !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
buttonb.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

    buttona.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         buttonb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in on Create method you can set visibility as follows:

```
   button_b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and in the onclick method of button_a  make button_b visible as follows

```
    button_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         button_b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }    
    }
```